# Managing _blank links

Tags: c#, facebook, xulrunner

I'm using xulrunner to show some content from a website, it works perfectly for the most, but we have included a facebook like box with stream (div+javascript), and clicking on any link in it does nothing.
We would like to open it in a new window of the default browser, it's possible?

the code for the xulrunner is pretty simple

```
    private void Form_browser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        geckoBrowser.Navigate(Properties.Settings.Default.redirect);

    }
```